# Need clarification in Oracle DB 12.2 nls_length_semantics value

Tags: sql, oracle

In Oracle DB 12.2 , when the `nls_length_semantics` is `CHAR` we can able to  create a table with column having default value as below:

```
REFERENCE_NO  VARCHAR2(40) default
TO_CHAR(TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE@!,'YYDDD')))||'RR'||LPAD(TO_CHAR(SEQ_T.NEXTVAL),9,'0') not null
```

But when `nls_length_semantics` is `BYTE`, the above column creation is giving error:

> "ORA-01401 inserted value too large for column".

This issue resolves when we try with column length as 80 instead of 40. Can anyone tell me the significance of `nls_length_semantics` here.

Note: table column creation works fine with 16 in Oracle DB 12.1 irrespective of `nls_length_semantics` value.

Comment: when the nls_length_semantics is CHAR the size you define (in above example : 40) equals to 40 characters whereas if you set nls_length_semantics as BYTE then the size is 40 bytes. And single character may require 1 byte or 2 byte or 3bytes. hence the error : ORA-01401 inserted value too large for column in case of BYTE.

Comment: But the same is working with VARCHAR2(16) in Oracle DB 12.1, So what changed in 12.2 that too for CHAR and BYTE?